# Optimize JSTL and ORACLE query creation and run time

Tags: oracle, optimization, jstl, query-optimization

I have some code that does an oracle call. I was wondering if the way I am trying to do this can be done better or if the oracle code can be more efficient.

My main point of concern is doing a comparison on `UPPER('%Variable%')`. The wild cards WITHIN an upper seems potentially dangerously slow.

The result can return over 50k results(expected to grow heavily in the future).

The purpose of the 1=1 is simply so to make the rest of the code simpler and figured it can't hurt the sql too much.

```
<c:set var="sqltext">
    SELECT var1, var2, var3 from var_table
    WHERE 1=1
    <c:if test="${!empty param.var1}"> AND UPPER(var1) LIKE UPPER('%${param.var1}%')</c:if>
    <c:if test="${!empty param.var2}"> AND UPPER(var2) LIKE UPPER('%${param.var2}%')</c:if>
    <c:if test="${!empty param.var3}"> AND var3 = '${param.var3}'</c:if>
</c:set>
<sql:query var="data" dataSource="mydatasource" sql="${sqltext}"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing after some thorough research online was I removed all uses of UPPER and wildcards.

By having wildcards always there(mostly the leading wildcard) it removes the usage of indexes and makes it so that there is always a full table scan, even when it is not necessary. An alternative would be to use conText indexes, but they do not seem appropriate for my current application.

By removing the upper I simply made the search filter case sensitive, in which, after looking around the company websites, most of the search filters are case sensitive.

By removing the wildcards I simply force the user to have to input them into the search filters themselves. (This would be a very dangerous place for sql injections, but the project is for internal use only)

I ended up keeping the 1=1 to keep the code simple (it allows all my if conditions to start with `AND` statements instead of having to check whether another condition exists yet or not.